# How to show the names of each bone on an armature?

Tags: 3d-view, armature, bones

For example I have imported a dota 2 3d hero model and I need to attach my item to a particular bone but I cannot see the names of each of the bones.

Is there an option to enable display of the bone name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your armature selected you can go to the 'Armature' tab of the properties area and you can enable the 'Names' property in the 'Display' section:

[image]

Comment: Thanks sorry for asking what seem like very simple questions.

Comment: No problem :) . If this answer has helped you please check the tick icon next to my answer. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: There is no Display section in newer Blender. Where do I find it?

Comment: @AnsisMāliņš you can find it in Object Data Properties > Viewport Display

Answer (score 0):

While having the name shown can be helpful, it can still be hard to find a bone and impossible if the bone is hidden. Same applies to other objects for that matter.

By using the outliner you can easily search for an item by name. Items matching the search terms are highlighted in green, with only the parents of matching items remaining visible in the outliner.

[image]

Here we find thigh.L and thigh.R - We can see that thigh.R is hidden as the eye icon is not visible. By clicking on the name we have selected thigh.L, the bone layers show a yellow dot that the selected bone is on and that bone layer is not currently visible.